# Assigning a table to a session in PHP

Tags: php

The following validates only one text box (`txt1`). If I have a series of text boxes which lies in side a table (which is dynamically populated) how do I assign that entire values of the text boxes to one single session?

Is it possible if at all?

Or else can you suggest me a way out?

```
       <?php
        if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
           {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
            {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {$_SESSION['loged'] = $_POST['txt1'];}
           }
        if(isset($_POST['sendt']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
        {if(isset($_SESSION['loged'])) echo $_SESSION['loged']; echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!</rd></tr>"; 
        ?>
```

Comment: Dont forget to protect from XSS

Comment: how? can u suggest me what vulnerabilities u see? thanks

Comment: man, session variables are very heavy for server, don't do it or try to minimize the use of it

Answer (score 0):

```
   //try this
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
       {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
        {echo 'txt1 is empty!';} else {$_SESSION['loged'] = $_POST['txt1'];}
       }
    if(isset($_POST['sendt']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
    {
    if(isset($_SESSION['loged'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['loged']; 
    echo " border='1'>form 2 is here!";
    }
} 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I wasn't sure what you meant:

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
       {
       if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
        {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;}
       else{
          foreach($_POST as $Key => $Posted)
            $_SESSION[$Key] = $Posted;
          }
       }
    if(isset($_POST['sendt']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
    {if(isset($_SESSION['loged'])) echo $_SESSION['loged']; echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!</rd></tr>"; 
    ?>
```